# Image.complete is true after onload, but after onload second image not anymore

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I'm using Javascript to load 2 images and drawing them on a canvas.
I use the onload event of an image to drawn the images after they are both loaded.

```
var loadedImagesCount = 0;
var NUM_OF_TILES=2;

window.onload=function(){
    background.onload = imageOnLoad();
    background.src ="background.png";                   
    layer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
    ctx1 = layer1.getContext("2d");
    character.onload = imageOnLoad();
    character.src ="character.png";
    layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
    ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
}
                        
function imageOnLoad(){
    loadedImagesCount++;
    window.alert(''+loadedImagesCount+ ' ' + background.complete + ' ' + character.complete);
    if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES) drawAll();
                        }
```

The `imageOnLoad()` is called twice (as expected). The first time is says (through an alert) that both images are loaded. The second time it says that the character image is loaded, but the background image not anymore? How is this possible? Why would it unload the image again? After a refresh this does not happen anymore, it only happens the first time you load the page.

And because the background is not loaded, when the canvas is drawn, only the character is being drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The onload variable needs a method without the parentheses, if you use the parentheses it will call the method immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because you have not declared background as a global variable outside of the window.onload function. So background is not the variable you think it is.

Check this code that works as expected and is derived from yours and notice how background and characters are "vared" outside of the window.onload function :

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

var loadedImagesCount = 0;
var NUM_OF_TILES=2;
var background;
var character;

window.onload=function(){

    background = document.getElementById("background");
    character = document.getElementById("character");

    background.onload = imageOnLoad();
    background.src ="HSHOP.jpg";   
    character.onload = imageOnLoad();
    character.src ="HSHOP 2.jpg";

}

function imageOnLoad(){

    loadedImagesCount++;
    window.alert(''+loadedImagesCount+ ' ' + background.completes + ' ' + character.complete);
    //if (loadedImagesCount==NUM_OF_TILES) drawAll();
 }
</script>
<body>
<img id="background"/>
<img id="character"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Quick note : As a general rule try to clean up your code as much as possible before posting it so that it is easier for us to find what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the global variables: var layer1; var layer2; var ctx1; var ctx2; var background = new Image(); var character = new Image();

Comment: Try to check the differences between my post and your code. Mine works.

Comment: I found my error: onload=imageOnLoad() was wrong, onload=imageOnLoad is correct, because the first one immediately class the method, the second one waits for the event.